# What is the best way to initiate an AngularJS controller function that uses a service that make an HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, json, dependency-injection

I'm new on AngularJS. I would like to know what is the best way to use pure AngularJS to initiate a controller that uses a service that makes an HTTP request to an external source and as a response receives a JSON object.

The controller is being used to fetch information that will be shown as part of the landing page (welcome information).

I have tried:

1. In the HTML invoke the function with the `ng-init`, with alias for the controller and without alias.
2. In the controller make the explicit call to the service, and in the configuration of routes, resolve primitive to call the Service and save it a a variable at the configuration file.
3. In the controller receive as a parameter the response of the service and in the configuration of routes, use the resolve primitive to call the Service and save it as a variable with the name of the parameter that the controller receives.
4. In the controller save the response as a `$scope` variable, but it is always undefined an nothing is bound to the HTML. Is it necessary to create a value or a directive or something for saving an object in the scope? Also tried doing it at the service with $scope as parameter with the same results (undefined $scope variable).

These options effectively trigger the HTTP request and pass through the lines of the controller function. The problem is that the response is not available for the controller. Under debug mode I can only see that is an object but it doesn't behaves as a JSON object so can't access to none of the properties.

I used the .then at the controller, but although now the data is saved in the $scope, it shows [OBJECT OBJECT] and I can't access to the properties of the JSON object that is saved as the response of the http request. Any ideas?

The function of the service that makes the request like the following:

```
myAppModule.factory('ClimateService', function ($http) {
     return { 
      getLocation: function () {
            return $http.get("some_url/json")
            then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;    
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    //
  });
        }
     }

});
```

Under debug I can see the 200 response and the JSON of it. `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8`

After several changes, none of them are triggering and I am getting an injection error. I have included the local `angular-routes` in the HTML header, fetched with `bower.jason` to the project at NetBeans. And included as the first dependency or parameter to the ngRoute

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute', ...

angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute', 'app.core'])
    .config(config);

angular.module('app.core', []);
```

By the way, the Angello project at GitHub injects neither services nor much parameters and the book doesn't cover this topic in depth.

Is it the version of AngularJS?

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dapp.config%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dapp.config%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A494%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A333)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8383%252Fapp_demo_app%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A391%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A134%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fapp_demo_app%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463) (23:05:42:235 | error, javascrip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky because you have to use promises (.then), but here's a super simple 'get' example.

On the Service:

```
function mainService($http) {

  this.getData = function () {

    return $http.get('/api/yourUrl') //a basic 'get' api call
        .then(function (response) { //it takes time, so include a promise
            return response.data; 
        });
  };
}
```

And the Controller:

```
function homeController($scope, friendService) {

$scope.getData = function () {

    mainService.getData()
        .then(function (data) { //you also need a promise on controller

            $scope.ourData = data; //finally put what you get on your scope
        });
  };
}
```

Note these examples don't show the defining of the controller and the service - let me know if you're confused.

Comment: I only used the .then (.... at the service. I'll try including it also in the controller. Thanks

Comment: I used now the promise on the controller, and it is now showing in the site [OBJECT OBJECT]. I updated the question with how I am making the request.

Comment: the object object could just be the way you're logging it in the console. Sometimes getting data can be a bit tricky - I always log the response that I get back and see if I need to drill down on the object further. For example, sometime's it's just `response.data` other time's it's `response.data.data` and so on

Answer (score 1):

let's suppose you'll use $http service to request data.

```
angular.module('app.core', [])
  .controller('CoreController', CoreController);

CoreController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function CoreController($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert('something odd happens.');
  });
};
```

in your html

```
<div ng-bind-html="data">
</div>
```

or if you want to fill a form input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data" />
```

Comment: Is the instruction line <<< CoreController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']; >>> the same like: angular.module('app.core', [])
  .controller('CoreController', '$scope', '$http',
function CoreController($scope, $http) {

}

Comment: Implementing the function of the controller in the way you posted like a declaration and then the implementation after a ; is not recognizing it. I am now getting a  `code` Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=CoreController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)  `code` as it if wasn't a defined function. ( is not a function, got undefined)

Comment: using {{ data }} inside <div> isn't incorrect but you can have many html safe problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I am suggesting few things to keep in mind . May be its not what you are looking for but it might help.

1. `ng-init` is called as the very first thing inside a controller. You can use `promise` in case you have to keep things in sync.
2. If you dont want to get into promise, simply do `$http` call from controller as it by default handles promise using `.success` & `.error` function.
3. You can't expect some `$scope` variable to be valid under html if it is inside service. Refer docs.

   ```
   var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
   mainApp.controller("serviceController",function($scope,$http){
         $http.get("/fetchData_url/").success(function(response){
           $scope.data = response;
        });
   });
   ```

Comment: I used the ng-init calling a function of the controller to call the service because it didn't made the $http request without explicitly forcing it. Is it necesary something to specify a funcion of a controller should autorun when loading? I read that with angularJS the $window.load don't work.  I'll create a new projec since I have the injection error and I didn't saved the version that called the service.

Comment: I also assigned in another variation to variables of the controller. Something like var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
mainApp.controller("serviceController",function($scope,$http, MyService){
     var main = this;
      main.loadResponse= MyService.makeRequest().then(function(response){   
              
            main.unread = response.data['unread'];        
    });
              
       
}); Previously without the .then promise.

Comment: You must call a function one way or another. whether its `ng-init` or `ng-click` type events or from some other function itself. assigning value to `main.unread` wont get rendered on html page. It should be from `$scope` variables. I would suggest you to put some code over here , both  angular and html, so that we can provide exact answer.Better to edit ur actual ques rather than putting codes in comments :)